# JQuery datatables sort on different source

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using JQuery datatables plugin and works really well. Problem I have is sorting a date field. The date field is the first field in the table.

For a better UX (because day of the week is an important factor) I want to show dates in ascending order like this:

```
Fri 4th July 2014
Thu 10th July 2014
Fri 18th July 2014
```

When I load the table into `datatables` it sort the field thus:

```
Fri 18th July 2014
Fri 4th July 2014
Thu 10th July 2014
```

Which is alpha numeric. Not good for dates.

Is there any way I can add a field to the `<td>` e.g. `<td data-sort="2014-05-06">` and have it sort according to that variable instead of just the cell contents for that particular column?

I have searched their docs and API but can't see an immediate solution.

Comment: see datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html
use `data-order=(date in timestamp format) `

Comment: That's exactly it! Many thanks - if you want to add it as answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually in my question... I guessed what the solution should be without trying it as I couldn't find any reference to it.

tl;dr

```
<td data-sort="2014-05-06">
```

Many thanks @TamilSelvan

You can also use timestamp as suggested below

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-order=(date in timestamp format)`

```
<td data-order="1332975600">Thu 29th Mar 12</td>
```

Refer: http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html